# Find a holomorphic function that matches the following conditions

Tags: complex-analysis

I have to find a holomorphic function $f:\mathbb{D} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ that matches:

a) $e^{f(z)-z}=z^2-1$

b) $f(0)=\pi i$

Tried going for the obvious $f(z)=\log{(z^2-1)}+z$, because of b) we know that it must be the principal branch, and because $z^2-1$ has no roots in $\mathbb{D}$, $f(z)$ is holomorphic in $\mathbb{D}$. Is that correct?

Comment: You mean $\log(z^2-1)+z$, not $\log(z^2-1+z)$, right?

Comment: Yes, got mixed up. And it makes solving it easier too.

Comment: Thought it might :)

Answer (score 1):

Principal branch of $\log$ is usually defined in $\mathbb{C}\setminus (-\infty,0]$. So, using this branch you would have 
$$f(z)=\log(1-z^2) + z +\pi i$$

---

What you wrote works too if you use a branch of $\log $ that is defined in some domain containing $\{z:|z+1|<1\}$ and satisfies $\log(-1)=\pi i$. But this is not what I'd call the principal branch.